# Binary file installed by conda differs from one on anaconda.org

Tags: conda

The binary placed in the the `bin/` folder by `conda install wgrib2=2.0.5=1` and the binary file in the tarball on anaconda.org (1) differ. Is this expected, what could cause this?

1. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/wgrib2/2.0.5/download/linux-64/wgrib2-2.0.5-1.tar.bz2

---

For context, I encountered this while debugging [another issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/wgrib2-feedstock/issues/17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conda Prefix Editing

Not sure on all the details, but my understanding is that some<sup>**1**</sup> binaries when linking out to shared libraries make use of the environment's prefix (i.e., its path). In order to deal with this, Conda builds the binary with a placeholder prefix (see `info/has_prefix` and `info/paths.json` files), and then replaces this placeholder in the binary before placing it in the environment location. Since this involves editing the binary, it will no longer match the original sha256 sum.

Moreover, since environment locations are unique, installing an identical version of the binary in a different environment will yield a different hash. For example, creating an environment `foo` with `wgrib2`, then another environment `bar` using `conda create --clone foo`, gives two different hashes:

```bash
$ sha256sum envs/foo/bin/wgrib2 
ed77630abbfa150060b43219b233a6226b778a035120cd266cdc7082cf2b9d2b  envs/foo/bin/wgrib2

$ sha256sum envs/bar/bin/wgrib2 
92eef4bcdea0263c33b1dcfeb8d405e3147a09392b48675d45b444e16754ac06  envs/bar/bin/wgrib2
```

However, the version of the binary still in your package cache (defaults to `pkgs/`), should match that which you would download from the Anaconda Cloud interface, as in OP. I confirmed this is the case for your specific example.

---

<sub>**[1]** This is what I am most unclear about: why some binaries require this while others do not.</sub>

---

### Additional Info

FWIW, here are the relevant sections from running `conda install` with full verbosity. Observe that in the verification step, Conda copies the original binary to a temporary location under the environment, and then proceeds to update the binary in place to rewrite where it should resolve linked libraries.

```bash
Verifying transaction: ...working... 

TRACE conda.gateways.disk:mkdir_p(66): making directory /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/.condatmp
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:verify(417): copying /home/user/software/miniconda3/pkgs/wgrib2-2.0.5-1/bin/wgrib2 => /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/.\
condatmp/b994fd18-c6bd-46aa-ad74-29d6ce33a791
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.create:_do_copy(314): copying /home/user/software/miniconda3/pkgs/wgrib2-2.0.5-1/bin/wgrib2 => /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/\
foo/.condatmp/b994fd18-c6bd-46aa-ad74-29d6ce33a791
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:verify(422): rewriting prefixes in /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/bin/wgrib2
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:update_file_in_place_as_binary(38): in-place update path locked for /spacex/home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/.condatmp/b994f\
d18-c6bd-46aa-ad74-29d6ce33a791
done

Executing transaction: ...working... 

INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(742): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::wgrib2-2.0.5-1 <===
  prefix=/home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo
  source=/home/user/software/miniconda3/pkgs/wgrib2-2.0.5-1

TRACE conda.core.path_actions:execute(374): linking None => /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/bin
TRACE conda.gateways.disk:mkdir_p(66): making directory /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/bin
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:execute(447): linking /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/.condatmp/b994fd18-c6bd-46aa-ad74-29d6ce33a791 => /home/user/soft\
ware/miniconda3/envs/foo/bin/wgrib2
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.create:create_link(360): hard linking /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/.condatmp/b994fd18-c6bd-46aa-ad74-29d6ce33a791 => /home/f\
anslerm/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/bin/wgrib2
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:execute(900): creating linked package record /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/conda-meta/wgrib2-2.0.5-1.json
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.create:write_as_json_to_file(110): writing json to file /home/user/software/miniconda3/envs/foo/conda-meta/wgrib2-2.0.5-1.json
```